# What's the use of Allotment Partner in sale order line?

Tags: odoo

Can anyone tell me what's the use of Allotment Partner in sale order line? The narration given in **"A Partner to whom the particular product needs to be allotted"**. We already defined the customer is sale order right, then why is that info to be repeated again? I just want to know if there's a reason behind it. Thanks for your time..!!

Answer (score 0):

That is to handle a special case where one or more products in the Sale order is to be shipped to different partner (may be a branch office of the customer). It was hanging there from earlier version of OpenERP and there was some report based on that fields. I do not think that field got any functionality now.